# Can't see some image on chrome that i can in Firefox - css

Tags: html, css

I have exactly the same code, but on Firefox, i can see two images that i have set at the middle top of the page, but we can't see them on Chrome, maybe because i'm using `z-index`, don't really know..

Here is the plunker code.. [Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/4BizatqN0GkGc7nedoBF?p=preview)

**Mozilla :**

[image]

**Chrome :**

[image]

Thanks again!

Comment: Looks the same to me, maybe post 2 images showing exactly where the problem is?

Comment: At the time of writing, there is 500 errors on https://run.plnkr.co/uhZGcFYEs2X8zUYX/excel.png, and every images with this origin. That might be why :-)

Comment: My bad, i forgot to upload my image on plunker, this is why.. @autra

Comment: I added the two images showing exactly where the problem is @MaorRefaeli

Comment: Please do not link to your code, instead, include it in the post. If the link goes away, this question means nothing.

Comment: Go to preview.css line 33 and 34, i added them in the background of the label @CarolMcKay

Comment: even firefox also not working this. please check you image path. i meant 'excel.png'

Comment: It works, like i said before, it's because i can't upload local file on the plunker, but with a img that is stocked with the good path, it works only in firefox.. @RaviChauhan

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<label class="img_vis ch_excel" for="ch_excel"></label>
```

put a word or more in there for accessibility and also, it will create a gap for the browsers to work with, yes, they can be like that:

```
<label class="img_vis ch_excel" for="ch_excel">click me if you wanna buy a burger</label>
```

hide the text visually but not from screen readers:

```
label.img_vis
{
   position:absolute;
   width:1px;
   height:1px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

if you put this css you will see it's there (in grey?):

```
.ch_excel {
   border:2px solid red;
   background-color:red;
 }
```

Comment: I keep sawing nothing.. (btw the css border will be in red and not grey). @CarolMcKay

Comment: By the way, when I delete the .top-page node, I can see both images (because they are behind, despite the fact that I put a bigger z-index ...).